# How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in Java..And I also want to print just 2 number after the point

Tags: java

I am trying to print this integer `12345679` like `1,234,68`. I was trying to do like this.

```
System.out.println(count+" "+"$"+fm.format(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(avg)));
```

How can I do this in java??

Comment: how did you derive  1,234,68 out of 123456789?

Comment: @KickButtowski It's actually `12345679` (without 8), not `123456789`, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
currencyInstance.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
System.out.println(currencyInstance.format(12345679));
```

Output: $12,345,679

Comment: This doesn't yield `1,234,68` as requested by the OP. It also adds two decimal places, `.00`, even if the value was an integer. This is almost certainly not what the OP wants.

Comment: Edited. Boris, I think you're right about decimal places. I was confused with only 2 digits after last comma. Looks like typo. OP wants to format integer number.

Comment: "Looks like a typo" is not a valid enough reason - until the OP explains that its a typo it could be anything.